# Executing jpa query within a loop gives null

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm trying to run a jpa select query within a loop and add its' result to a list. But I'm getting null.

Here's what I've done :

```
String[] splittedTag = tagName.split("\\s+");

String getTags;
Query query;

for(String tag : splittedTag)
{
    getTags = "select distinct f.tagname from Filemetadata f where f.tagname LIKE '%"+tag+"%'";
    query = entityManager.createQuery(getTags);
    list.addAll(query.getResultList());
}
```

Later I use patterns to filter my results according the splitted tags and when there's a match in the results with all the splitted tags, I add that result into a jsonArrayBuilder and return it to a calling method.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(stringPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if (pattern.matcher((CharSequence) list.get(i)).find()) 
    {
        jsonArrayBuilder.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
return jsonArrayBuilder;
```

Is the query used the right way? Is it possible to be used this way? Help me figure and would greatly appreciate your help and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: WHAT is null????? A query result row? The "list"? something else?

Comment: I got it fixed, instead of loop, I appended "AND LIKE %string% for each splitted tag and then run the query at once.

Answer (score 0):

The query is a normal SQL Query, not HQL query, so, you have to call:

```
query = entityManager.createSQLQuery(getTags);
```

instead of:

```
query = entityManager.createQuery(getTags);
```

Another type, for performance, try to not do a lot of querys. In your code, if the list has 1.000 tags, yo will do 1.000 calls to database. Try to group in groups of 100 / 200 tags to reduce the database calls.

Comment: Thanks for the response, If I run this query without a loop only for this time, it works using `createQuery(getTags);` and if it's inside the loop is when it doesn't work. How is this different from createSQLQuery? like when I'm using JPA?

Comment: Is my mistake, you are using HQL query, not SQL. Is rigth to use "createQuery".

Try to print the Querys in the log and see wich query fails.